# UniformGrid and ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol, itemsource, uniformgrid

I have a `UniformGrid`. Inside, I would like to put a `Grid` which contains 2 children - and `Image` and a `Canvas`. I already have a `List<Grid>` member which contains a `Grid` with that definition.

I'm updating the source of the `Image` from `null` to an actual image, expecting the image to be shown inside the `UniformGrid`, but nothing happens.

Here's my code:

**Xaml:**

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" >
        <ItemsControl x:Name="StreamsItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Streams}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid x:Name="StreamsGrid"  ClipToBounds="True" Height="300" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private List<Grid> m_streams = new List<Grid>();
public List<Grid> Streams
        {
            get { return m_streams; }
            set
            {
                m_streams = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Streams");
            }
        }
```

**Edit: Adding more code:**

```
    public struct StreamContainer
    {
        public string StreamName;
        public Grid StreamGrid;
        public Canvas StreamCanvas;
        public Image StreamImage;
    }
    private readonly List<StreamContainer> m_streamsContainer = new List<StreamContainer>();

    public SequencesPlayerViewModel()
    {
        RegisterStream("Color");
        RegisterStream("Depth");
        RegisterStream("Ir");
        RegisterStream("Left");
    }

    private void RegisterStream(string streamName)
    {
        StreamContainer streamContainer;

        streamContainer.StreamName = streamName;
        streamContainer.StreamCanvas = new Canvas { Name = streamName + "Canvas", Background = Brushes.Transparent, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top };
        streamContainer.StreamImage = new Image { Name = streamName + "Image", Stretch = Stretch.Uniform, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top };

        var widthBinding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth") };
        var heightBinding = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight"),
            Source = streamContainer.StreamImage
        };


        streamContainer.StreamCanvas.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, heightBinding);
        streamContainer.StreamCanvas.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, widthBinding);

        streamContainer.StreamGrid = new Grid { Name = streamName + "Grid" };
        streamContainer.StreamGrid.Children.Add(streamContainer.StreamImage);
        streamContainer.StreamGrid.Children.Add(streamContainer.StreamCanvas);

        streamContainer.StreamGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        m_streamsContainer.Add(streamContainer);
    }

    private void AddStream(StreamContainer currentStream)
    {
        var listOfStreams = GetListOfStream();

        if (listOfStreams.Count > 0)
        {
            var streamToAdd = listOfStreams.Find(currStream => currStream.Name == currentStream.StreamName);
            if (streamToAdd != null)
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentStream.StreamName))
                {
                    currentStream.StreamGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    (currentStream.StreamGrid.Children[0] as Image).Source = streamToAdd.ImageBitmap;
                }
        }

        Streams.Add(currentStream.StreamGrid);
    }

    private void OnNewFrameReady(uint frameNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            var listOfStreams = GetListOfStream();

            foreach (var elem in Streams)
            {
                var currentCanvas = (elem.Children[1] as Canvas);
                var canvasName = currentCanvas.Name.Split(new[] { "Canvas" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();

                var currentStream = listOfStreams.Find(currStream => currStream.Name == canvasName);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentStream.Name))
                    (elem.Children[0] as Image).Source = currentStream.ImageBitmap;
                Panel p = currentCanvas;
                elem.UpdateLayout();

                elem.Width = (elem.Children[0] as Image).ActualWidth;
                elem.Height = (elem.Children[0] as Image).ActualHeight;
                elem.UpdateLayout();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

The `ViewModel` is connected correctly, and the `Bindings` of the other controls are working properly.

I can also see that the `Streams` member is updated correctly, meaning that the `Image` was correctly updated with the new `Source`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you adding items to the list and expecting them to show up? Are you changing the image source after the list of grids has already been loaded (need to show us the code used for binding that)?

Comment: Ok, I added more code. Basically I'm registering all `streams` to a `List`. Then, at some point, I'm calling the `OnNewFrameReady` function, which should update the `UniformGrid`. As for your questions: Yes, I'm adding items to the list, expecting them to show up, and Yes for the second question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is that your items are not showing up at all -- *not* that the image isn't updating (because I see you're updating the source property of the image element directly)... With a list, the `PropertyChanged` event will only fire when the `List<>` is changed, not when something is added to it, unlike the `ObservableCollection<>` which fires events when items are added/removed/replaced/cleared.

Try replacing your `List<>` with an `ObservableCollection<>` (found in `System.Collections.ObjectModel`)

Other than that, the `Grid` and `Image` could instead be defined in a `DataTemplate` within the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` and the `Source` bound to a property of a *stream* ViewModel (which is what you should have a collection of) -- but unrelated to the issue.

Comment: Worked!!! I replaced the `List` with `ObservableCollection` and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!!!